# Which tomato cultivars feature wrinkles?

Tags: tomatoes

The Pumpkin tomato, Beefsteak tomato, Raf tomato and "Cor de bou" (Catalan - in translation "Ox heart") are featuring (vertical) wrinkles - or furrows - not sure how to call them.

What other tomato cultivars feature wrinkles and what's the best name for such a tomato category? Wrinkled tomatoes? Or "Segmented tomatoes"?

This is a Beefsteak tomato: 
[image: Wrinkled]

Beefsteak and "Cor de bou" might be the same thing, as the French name of the above image suggests.

Comment: The french name is: coeur de boeuf

Comment: There are so many varieties that I think the question is impossible to answer. Like most of useful species, crossbreeding and hybridization are very frequent (improving size, durability, storage period, handling, and maybe also taste)

Comment: Well at least the most popular of them that feature wrinkles. Still, not sure how to categorize them: wrinkled? segmented? furrowed?

Comment: I think it is "ribbed"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They call them ribbed tomatoes (you can also find ribbed cantaloupes/melons, eggplants and peppers). Some people use the word 'fluted'. There are a lot of tomatoes with some degree of ribbing. Some are a lot more ribbed than others. Some of the most highly ribbed tomatoes I've found include at least the following:

- Pink Stuffer AKA Tlacalula AKA Tlacalula Ribbed AKA Tlacolula AKA Tlacolula Ribbed AKA Tlacolula Pink
- Zapotec AKA Zapotec Pink Pleated
- Pink Accordian
- Yellow Ruffled AKA [Yellow Ruffed](https://www.mariannasheirloomseeds.com/heirloom-seeds-catalog/mariseeds-heirloom-tomato-seeds/yellow-orange-tomatoes/yellow-ruffed-detail.html)

I've grown all of those, although my Pink Accordian wasn't true to type.

Marmande, Brandywine, [Costoluto Genovese](http://www.rareseeds.com/costoluto-genovese-tomato/), [Costoluto Florentino](http://www.rareseeds.com/costoluto-florentino-tomato/), and Tim's Black Ruffles, are some more examples of ribbed tomatoes. They don't seem quite as ribbed, perhaps, but they're still fairly ribbed.

Not all ribbed tomatoes are consistently ribbed.

Beefsteak, although it is a variety name, is also a tomato shape (although I'm unclear on whether ribbing is required). To confuse matters more, there appears to be a lot of variance between the Beefsteak variety as sold by different vendors. The two I grew were fairly small, perfectly round, smooth tomatoes (nothing like your picture): mine were from Peaceful Valley and American Seed; they didn't have a beefsteak shape (yours looks more like a pear shape than a beefsteak to me, though). I discovered after a fair amount of research that some entities mean Red Ponderosa / Crimson Cushion when they say Beefsteak. Others may just mean any tomato with the beefsteak shape (there must be thousands of those varieties). Some people also consider beefsteaks to simply be large tomatoes (see Wikipedia; the article there takes that angle).

Anyway, beefsteak is an ambiguous term; it looks like the general consensus is probably that a beefsteak is a large slicer and/or Red Ponderosa / Crimson Cushion and/or a ribbed tomato with an oblate shape.